# Word for someone who has used excessive amounts of perfume/cologne

Tags: single-word-requests

Excessive levels of perfume or cologne is an issue for many people in the workplace. For example, [this article](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/tell-employees-not-wear-excessive-perfume-17615.html) describes how to implement a policy against the overuse of such toiletries.

I would like to know if there exists any single words describing the overuse of fragrances.

Comment: "Stinky" would seem to fit nicely.

Comment: It is probably a whole lot easier than having to deal with an employee who has body odour!

Comment: I would just hyphenate and use *over-perfumed* which conveys the meaning pretty much exactly.

Comment: *odoriferous*, or perhaps *overly odoriferous*.

Comment: @ermanen Thanks for that, for some reason it didn't show up on a crude search.

Answer (score -1):

A ***philistine*** is a person whose financial means exceed his or her cultural and/or spiritual level.

They are notorious for their overuse of perfume/cologne, their hairdo's, their tawdry wardrobe, their souped-up cars, etc.

Comment: Neither [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/philistine) nor [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Philistine) supports your definition. Can you link to the source of your definition?

Comment: @MarchHo: Yes, they do. Specifically, the very first definition in Dictionary.com does.